# How do we show a notification in the OS with React Native and Android?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-play-services, react-native-firebase

So I just set up a Firebase function to send notifications to my devices and I added react-native-firebase to my project so I signin, get a token and receive notifications.

The notification is getting received by the device, but I dont know how to show it in the UI. I wanted to show that box with a message with some text and eventually an icon.

What library should I use now? I tried to install react-native-push-notifications to use the local notification feature. But there seems to be a conflict with versions of Google Services both libraries use

What should i do?